# Objectify query result mystery

Tags: android, google-app-engine, objectify

I have an entity w/ @Id in String type and I managed to insert one record.

When I execute the query below, I am able to see the record returned by the query:

ofy().transactionless().load().type(Score.class).first().now();

However, when I try to query via the id() method, I got zero record.

ofy().transactionless().load().type(Score.class).id("idstring").now;

Any idea what may I have missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query is just producing the first Score entity in the datastore. The second query is looking for a specific key. You probably have the id specified incorrectly.

Also, you almost certainly don't need transactionless() - that is a very special use case.

Comment: Hi, Stickfigure:  I verified the id value (copy and paste from the datastore viewer).  That's the mystery that I can't solve.  There's only one record, so I should get a record returned by the 2nd statement.  The reason I use transactionless(), because I invoke it w/n the Work()/run()....i can't run non-parent query in this method.

Comment: Without more information (ie, all the code around this) it's hard to give you any advice. However, I can tell you with 100% confidence, if you're loading an entity with the type().id() methods and you aren't getting the result you expect, it's because you are specifying the key incorrectly vis a vis what's in the datastore. Maybe there is a @Parent you are ignoring?

Comment: Stickfigure...you might be onto something here.  The entity does have @parent field.  I also noticed something "funny":  I inserted the record with the parent field populated, but it's not displaying in the datastore viewer.  I wonder if this is causing the query to fail.  Any more insight?  Thanks!